# Nested IF statements with VLOOKUPs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to created a nested IF statement that says, for example, IF A2 is equal to x, x, x posting codes then pull data from the revenue column, IF A2 is equal to y, y, y posting codes then pull data from Bad Debt column and so on for 6 different possible results. Only 3 of the 6 are VLOOKUPs. The other 3 are just if A2=Z then "1024".

I will copy what code I currently have, but it's not pretty. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
=IF(G2="100",G2="101",G2="102",G2="105",G2="106",G2="170",G2="171",G2="173",G2="200",G2="210",G2="220",G2="230",G2="250",G2="300",G2="301",G2="302",G2="304",G2="305",G2="306",G2="307",G2="308",G2="309",G2="310",G2="312",G2="313",G2="314",G2="315",G2="316",G2="317",G2="318",G2="319",G2="320",G2="321",G2="322",G2="323",G2="324",G2="325",G2="326",G2="327",G2="328",G2="329",G2="330",G2="331",G2="332",G2="333",G2="334",G2="335",G2="336",G2="337",G2="338",G2="339",G2="340",G2="341",G2="342",G2="343",G2="344",G2="345",G2="346",G2="360",G2="370",G2="372",G2="379",G2="382",G2="383",G2="385",G2="390",G2="402",G2="403",G2="404",G2="405",G2="414",G2="415",G2="416",G2="417",G2="418",G2="419",G2="420",G2="421",G2="425",G2="427",G2="428",G2="429",G2="440",G2="441",G2="442",G2="443",G2="444",G2="445",G2="447",G2="472",G2="477",G2="480",G2="501",G2="600",G2="700",G2="800",G2="900",vlookup('AR Credit'!A2,Guarantors!A:D,3,FALSE),IF(G2="347",G2="384",G2="399",G2="406",G2="499",G2="801",vlookup('AR Credit'!A2,Guarantors!A:D,5,FALSE),IF(G2="348",G2="354",G2="355",G2="357",G2="377",G2="601",vlookup('AR Credit'!A2,Guarantors!A:D,4,FALSE),IF(G2="120",G2="150",G2="151",G2="152",G2="153",G2="154","1051",IF(G2="400","1385",IF(G2="500","2036",IF(G2="172","3783","Null"))))))))
```

Comment: Did you try formula auditing for solving your issue?

Comment: break your formula down to a smaller group to get the concept working then expand case or ranges to meet your needs

Comment: `IF` functions are broken into 3 areas, each separate by a`,` (or `;` depending on regional settings).   `IF`( `TRUE/FALSE CONDITION` , `WHAT TO DO FOR TRUE` , `WHAT TO DO FOR FALSE`).  After your very first IF, you have too many `,`.  I would hazard a guess that you nee to put all those G2=___ inside OR(). after the or you will have a `,` then you put what to do when the OR is true.  Then another `,` and what you will do when the OR is false.

Comment: since there are only 6 possible results, can you state what those conditions are and what you want to happen for each condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of fixing your issue is by using `OR`, specifically wrapping your cases in it like in this example:

```
=OR(G2="100",G2="101",G2="102",G2="105")
```

This will result in `TRUE` if any of conditions is met, otherwise `FALSE`.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work either.I used an OR around each Case. It says there's a problem with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous errors with your formula. You could get it working by following Zipa's answer and using the OR function. However, it would be a nightmare to maintain if anything changes in future.

I would recommend creating a look up table for the values and results. It could then be queried like so:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$98,$A2)>0,$E$1,
    IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$98,$A2)>0,$F$1,
        IF(COUNTIFS($G$2:$G$98,$A2)>0,$G$1,
            IF(COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$98,$A2)>0,$H$1,
                IF(COUNTIFS($I$2:$I$98,$A2)>0,$I$1,
                    IF(COUNTIFS($J$2:$J$98,$A2)>0,$J$1,
                        IF(COUNTIFS($K$2:$K$98,$A2)>0,$K$1,"NULL")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

See the image below for illustration:

[image]

Where I have put "Opt1", "Opt2" in the results row, you can put your VLOOKUPs (although I would recommend INDEX/MATCH instead) or your hard coded values.

This way, you can easily see (and modify) which group each code is in. Even adding more groups wouldn't be too difficult.

Obviously, you could move the table onto a different sheet if you wished.